# Ticking all checkboxes generated in a CollectionView in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

I have a collection view filled with a List, comprised of a checkbox and a label :

```
<CollectionView x:Name="cvPreferences">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <CheckBox Grid.Column="0"    x:Name="{Binding}" ClassId="{Binding}" HeightRequest="30" IsChecked="False" CheckedChanged="chkPref_Checked"/>
                <Label    Grid.Column="1"    Text="{Binding}"    HeightRequest="30" FontSize="Small" Margin="2,6,0,0" />
                <ImageButton Grid.Column="2" ClassId="{Binding}" HeightRequest="30" Source="delete_pref.png" Clicked="btnDeletePref_Clicked"/>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

This is populated with a global variable :

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    List<String> prefsTargetFolderList = new List<String>();
    ...
```

And somewhere in my code, it's populated like this :

```
cvPreferences.ItemsSource = prefsTargetFolderList.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

I'd like to have a button to select everything.
As I specified the x:Name and ClassId I thought I'll be able to get all the checkboxes and tick them.
However, for every item in prefsTargetFolderList, the checkbox is null.

```
private void btnSelectAllPrefs_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check if checking it with code triggers the stuff
    foreach (string pref in prefsTargetFolderList)
    { 
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)FindByName(pref);
        if (checkbox != null)
            checkbox.IsChecked = true;
    }
}
```

Any idea on ticking all checkboxes generated in a collection view ?

Comment: You need to update the model that the checkboxes are bound to, NOT update the checkbox UI directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look for MVVM pattern for it ([Link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm), [Link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm?view=net-maui-7.0)). Here is working version of your problem. If you want to have clean and understandable code, your code should be similar to this.

`XAML` Code;

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModel:ViewModelMainPage/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<StackLayout Spacing=" 20">
    <CollectionView x:Name="cvPreferences"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding PrefsTargetFolderList}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="30" IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckBoxChecked}" CheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged"/>
                    <Label    Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LabelText}" HeightRequest="30" FontSize="Small" Margin="2,6,0,0" />
                    <ImageButton Grid.Column="2" HeightRequest="30" Source="dotnet_bot.png" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"/>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
    <Button Text="Select All" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>
```

`Button_Clicked` event method;

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewModelMainPage viewModel = BindingContext as ViewModelMainPage;

    foreach (ModelCvPreferences item in viewModel.PrefsTargetFolderList)
    {
        item.IsCheckBoxChecked = true;
    }
}
```

`ViewModel` for your View;

```
internal class ViewModelMainPage
{

    public ObservableCollection<ModelCvPreferences> PrefsTargetFolderList
    {
        get
        {
            return prefsTargetFolderList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (prefsTargetFolderList != value)
            {
                prefsTargetFolderList = value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and finally a `Model` for keeping your states;

```
internal class ModelCvPreferences : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private bool isCheckBoxChecked = false;
    public bool IsCheckBoxChecked 
    {
        get 
        { 
            return isCheckBoxChecked; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            if (IsCheckBoxChecked != value)
            {
                isCheckBoxChecked = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsCheckBoxChecked));
            }
        }
    }

    private string labelText = "default text";
    public string LabelText
    {
        get
        {
            return labelText;
        }
        set
        {
            if (labelText != value)
            {
                labelText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LabelText));
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, for every item in prefsTargetFolderList, the checkbox is null.

First of all, it seems you can't use the x:Name to access the control in the `DataTemplate`. In addition, the `x:Name` is not a BindableProperty of the CheckBox, it's an attribute that maps the name or id property of the element to `x:Name`. So you can't use the binding such as `x:Name="{Binding}"`. You can refer to the official document about the [x:Name Directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xname-directive)

You can try to create a variable which is type of bool in the model to bind it to the CheckBox's IsChecked property. And change the property to set the CheckBox's state.

Answer (score 0):

For a generic collectionview i did it with this code:

```
    <CollectionView
    x:Name="UsersCollectionView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding UsersList}"
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
    SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding BuildCoichedUser}"
    SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding .,Source={x:Reference UsersCollectionView}}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border
            Stroke="{StaticResource Primary}"
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 5,5,5,5"
            StrokeThickness="1"
            Padding="5"
            WidthRequest="200"
            HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Yellow" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <HorizontalStackLayout
                HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Label
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    FontFamily="AppFontBold"
                    Text="{Binding Surname}"></Label>
                    <Label Text=" "></Label>
                    <Label
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    Text="{Binding Name}"
                    FontFamily="AppFontBold"></Label>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

I made also a button referenced to the collectionView

```
    <Button
Grid.Row="3"
Text="SELECT ALL"
HorizontalOptions="Center"
VerticalOptions="Center"
BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
Margin="0,10,0,20"
Command="{Binding SelectAll}"
CommandParameter="{Binding .,Source={x:Reference UsersCollectionView}}"></Button>
```

And in ViewModel

```
    public ICommand SelectAll => new Command<object>((collectionView) =>
    {
        CollectionView cw = (CollectionView)collectionView;
        cw.SelectedItems.Clear();
        foreach(object item in cw.ItemsSource)
        {
            cw.SelectedItems.Add(user);
        }
    });
```